# AirDrop: My iPhone appears as an option in my MacBook, but not the opposite

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, icloud, airdrop

I'm trying to user AirDrop from my iPhone to Mac, but my device doesn't show up. But I can share from my Mac to my iPhone.

It's can be something related to my company's internet connect because at my home it works out.

Basically, both devices are in the same network, with "everyone" set and same iCloud account. iCloud was reset on both devices.

`defaults write com.apple.NetworkBrowser BrowseAllInterfaces 1` is set.

Also, this behavior is happening only for me. Other colleagues have AirDrop working fine.

Any idea or what it can be?

Comment: AirDrop doesn't require an Internet connection to work. Neither is it required for both the devices to be connected to a Wi-Fi access point. Just need to have both Wi-Fi and Bluetooth turned-on on both the devices along with being setup as discoverable via AirDrop.

Comment: mostly the bugs are the smaller ones, are wifi and bluetooth turned on? like blue in iOS, not white.

Comment: AirDrop is very buggy.  I've seen people with the same settings in the same room have it not work for one but work for the other.  Sometimes doing a network reset works on the iOS device (you'll lose your stored login credentials).